# How to use `chain` with `lodash-es` while supports tree shaking?

Tags: javascript, method-chaining, lodash

As we all know, [`lodash-es`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/tree/es) is built with a more modular syntax for supporting tree shaking by build tools.

However, `chain` related features means some functions are attached to a object/prototype chain.

I can see `chain` is published with `lodash-es`, but I am not sure how to use it with proper imports with other chained method.

A usecase may look like this:

```
import { chain } from 'lodash-es'

export function double(input) {
    return chain(input)
        .without(null)
        .map(val => val * 2)
        .value()
        .join(', ')
}
```

#### Edit #1:

The point is not about how is `chain` imported, but about **how are other `chained` functions imported**.

Comment: Here is the github ticket regarding this question: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3298

Answer (score 14):

**EDIT**: as pointed out by Snook, there has been work on [a github issue](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3298#issuecomment-341685354) on this subject. So I've added this to my answer. Go to *Flow solution* for the previous answer (which is as good IMHO).

## Custom chain solution

```js
import map from 'lodash-es/map';
import filter from 'lodash-es/filter';
import mapValues from 'lodash-es/mapValues';
import toPairs from 'lodash-es/toPairs';
import orderBy from 'lodash-es/orderBy';
import groupBy from 'lodash-es/groupBy';
import sortBy from 'lodash-es/sortBy';

// just add here the lodash functions you want to support
const chainableFunctions = {
  map,
  filter,
  toPairs,
  orderBy,
  groupBy,
  sortBy,
};

export const chain = (input) => {
  let value = input;
  const wrapper = {
    ...mapValues(
      chainableFunctions,
      (f) => (...args) => {
        // lodash always puts input as the first argument
        value = f(value, ...args);
        return wrapper;
      },
    ),
    value: () => value,
  };
  return wrapper;
};
```

There is also a TypeScript version available at [lodash/lodash#3298](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3298#issuecomment-341685354).

## Flow solution

You can't, `chain` needs to bundle all (or most) lodash's functions.

You can use [`flow`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flow) though. Here is an example of converting this:

```
import _ from "lodash";

_.chain([1, 2, 3])
 .map(x => [x, x*2])
 .flatten()
 .sort()
 .value();
```

into this:

```
import map from "lodash/fp/map";
import flatten from "lodash/fp/flatten";
import sortBy from "lodash/fp/sortBy";
import flow from "lodash/fp/flow";

flow(
    map(x => [x, x*2]),
    flatten,
    sortBy(x => x) 
)([1,2,3]);
```

This example (and more) come from [this article](https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba).

Comment: I know `lodash/fp` is another way. But my question is about `lodash-es`. If we can't use `chain` with `lodash-es`, why is it published? Unless it's a design problem to expose it.

Comment: `lodash-es` is more about allowing tree-shaking if you only need access to specific utility functions. Chaining cannot be properly implemented in a modular fashion, as it would severely complicate the code-base if it were to still include lazy evaluation optimizations, and I suspect that would require hard-coding every possible combination of explicitly imported functions in order to be modular, which isn't feasible. Therefore it imports the entire functionality of lodash.

Comment: You can still use `_.mixin`, I'd really suggest you read the article in my answer :)

Comment: In fact, I've read the article before. Based on our discussion, since `chain` has no valid usecase under `lodash-es`, it seems it could be a design flaw for `lodash-es`. I may raise an issue on github.

Answer (score 1):

I found simpler, but tricker answer on how to build your own chain.

```
import * as ld, { wrapperLodash as _ } from 'lodash-es'

ld.mixin(_, {
  chain: ld.chain,
  map: ld.map
})
_.prototype.value = ld.value

const emails = _.chain(users)
  .map('email')
  .value()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### New answer

In `chain.js`, you see the first line is

```
import lodash from './wrapperLodash.js';
```

[If we go to that file](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/es/wrapperLodash.js), we'll find a long explanation about how chaining is implemented using lazy evaluation that can shortcut iteratees until the call to `value()`. Below that is an exported helper function defined like this:

```
function lodash(value) {
  if (isObjectLike(value) && !isArray(value) && !(value instanceof LazyWrapper)) {
    if (value instanceof LodashWrapper) {
      return value;
    }
    if (hasOwnProperty.call(value, '__wrapped__')) {
      return wrapperClone(value);
    }
  }
  return new LodashWrapper(value);
}
```

Going back to `chain.js`, we see how that is used in the `chain()` function:

```
function chain(value) {
  var result = lodash(value);
  result.__chain__ = true;
  return result;
}
```

Essentially, `chain()` checks the input to make sure it's not already a wrapped value, and if it is, it either returns the value if it's an instance of the correct class, or it returns a new wrapped value.

There are no methods attached to any native prototype chains in this implementation, but it does create a new class called `LodashWrapper` that wraps the input object with `lodash` functionality and lazy evaluation optimizations.

#### Old answer

I believe the correct `import` statement to apply tree-shaking would be

```es6
import chain from 'lodash-es/chain'
```

This imports the same module to the same variable as the `import` statement used in the question, but the difference is that running `import { chain } from 'lodash-es'` evaluates [*all* of the imports in `lodash.js`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/es/lodash.js), whereas my `import` method only touches the [`chain.js`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/es/chain.js) file and whatever its necessary dependencies are in `wrapperLodash.js`.

Comment: it's the same, see here: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/es/lodash.js

Comment: @e-cloud no, it's not the same. Running `import { chain } from 'lodash-es'` evaluates [_all_ of the imports in `lodash.js`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/es/lodash.js), whereas my `import` method only touches the [`chain.js`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/es/chain.js) file (and whatever its necessary dependencies are in `wrapperLodash.js`.

Comment: But with build tools with tree shaking, wouldn't it be the same?

Comment: @e-cloud yes, but since your question was specifically about what the proper syntax would be to apply tree-shaking without the help of bundling tools, this is my answer. If you're fine relying on the tools you have to do the tree-shaking for you at the transpiling stage, then your question isn't really a question, or you need to be more clear about what it is you want to know.

Comment: @e-cloud I hope my update addresses the question sufficiently

Comment: Thx for detail explanation. But it doesn't have any solution. You can see @ulysee-bn 's answer and my comment.

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternative flow solution with `lodash-es/flow`

I went with another approach, which doesn't rely on modifying lodash internals, and still keeps tree shaking.

```
import { flow, map, flatten, sortBy } from "lodash-es";

export const f = <V, I, R>(func: (v: V, i: I) => R, i: I) => (v: V) => func(v, i)

const value = flow([
    f(map, x => [x, x*2]),
    flatten,
    f(sortBy, x => x)
])([3,1,2])
```

The idea is to manually wrap each function that *normally* takes `(value, iteratee)` parameters with a higher-order function `f()` that also accepts the iteratee, and outputs a value-first equivalent. In other words, you convert the function to its `lodash/fp` behavior.

This adds a little extra syntax, but you might find it readable enough.